# How to merge two dict together while maintaining same structure but combining values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have 2 dict with same structure (this entire dict is the structure for any one of the dicts):

```
{
 '0': {
         'A': a,
         'B': b,
       },
 '1': {
         'C': c,
         'D': d,
       }
}

#Sample input and output:
#dict1
{
 '0': {
         'A': 0,
         'B': 1,
       },
 '1': {
         'C': 2,
         'D': 3,
       }
}

#dict2
{
 '0': {
         'A': 5,
         'B': 5,
       },
 '1': {
         'C': 5,
         'D': 5,
       },
 '3': { 'E': 5 } #this will be ignored when combining
}

#merged output with addition:
{
 '0': {
         'A': 5,
         'B': 6,
       },
 '1': {
         'C': 7,
         'D': 8,
       }
}
```

Ideally, everything about both dicts are the same except for the values a,b,c,d. For any subsequent dicts that have parts in their structure that are different from the first dict, those parts are ignored when merging. Like how the `3` AND `E` key in dict2 was ignored in the merge.

How can I combine both dicts into one dict that maintains the same structure, but with merged values? I would like to make this generic, so this 'merge' operation could be addition, subtraction, etc. And the number of dicts to merge can also change (not just 2 at a time).

Thanks, I hope to learn more about Python from your solutions

Comment: It is not very clear from the example which two `dict`s you want to merge - do you want to merge `0` with `1` or do you mean there are two `dict`s each with a key of `0` and `1`. What do you mean by `dict`s having different structure - do you mean they can have different keys or do you mean they can have different values? Best to provide a "Sample input" and a "sample output" for one of the more complex cases you have in mind

Comment: @Mortz Ah sorry about that, I just edited my post with a sample input and output

Answer (score 0):

This is to combine all the dicts, i.e, to merge.

```
d = {
 '0': {
         'A': a,
         'B': b,
       },
 '1': {
         'C': c,
         'D': d,
       },
}

def merge(d):
    merged_dict = {}

    for k in d:
        for key in d[k]:
            if not merged_dict.get(key, False):
                merged_dict[key] = d[k][key]

    return merged_dict

md = merge(d)
```

This should just merge the different `dict`s into one.

Comment: are you sure this program run in compiler?because its not run in pycharm

Comment: Well I tested the code and it ran good enough. Is it throwing an error.

Comment: @sourabmaity Are those the line numbers?

Comment: @sourabmaity Sorry I forgot to include the commas from the source code, recheck this code please.

Answer (score 0):

is you want that type of code

```
marged={}
for i in a:
    for j in a[i]:
        marged.setdefault(j,a[i].get(j))
print(marged)
```

Output:

```
{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'K': 'k', 'L': 'l', 'C': 'c', 'D': 'd'}
```

Input:

```
a={
 '0': {
         'A': "a",
         'B': "b",
        'K':"k",
        'L':"l"
       },
 '1': {
         'C': "c",
         'D': "d"
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use UPDATE method.
if a is a dictionary and you want to add another dictionary say b.
then simply use

```
a.update(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

For supporting arbitrary dict structure and nesting, you will have to use a recursive function. Pass the operator as a parameter and use e.g. `reduce` to calculate the value for all the passed dicts (one or more). This assumes only dicts of dicts, but could also handle e.g. lists with another block `if isinstance(first, list)` and a corresponding list comprehension.

```
import functools, operator

def merge(op, first, *more):
    if isinstance(first, dict):
        return {key: merge(op, first[key], *(d[key] for d in more if key in d))
                for key in first}for key in first}
    else:
        return functools.reduce(op, more, first)

A = {'0': {'A': 1, 'B':  2}, '1': {'C':  3, 'D':  4}}
B = {'0': {'A': 5, 'B':  6}, '1': {'C':  7, 'D':  8}}
print(merge(operator.add, A, B))
# {'0': {'A': 6, 'B': 8}, '1': {'C': 10, 'D': 12}}
```

Also works with more than two dicts, different operator, or if the `more` dicts have more or fewer keys than `first`:

```
C = {'0': {'A': 9, 'B': 10}, '1': {'C': 11, 'D': 12}}
D = {'0': {'A': 13, 'X': 14}, '2': {'C': 15, 'D': 16}}
print(merge(lambda x, y: f"{x}-{y}", A, B, C, D))
# {'0': {'A': '1-5-9-13', 'B': '2-6-10'}, '1': {'C': '3-7-11', 'D': '4-8-12'}}
```

It still assumes that values corresponding to the same keys in `first` and `more` have the same type, though.